# pnpm run build: error TS2345: Argumt of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PublishCommandInput' in "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane"

Tags: typescript, aws-iot, pnpm

I am running the command `pnpm run build` in a typescript code that is using `import { IoTDataPlaneClient, PublishCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane"`.

Following is the TS code:

```
import { IoTDataPlaneClient, PublishCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane"
const clientIoT = new IoTDataPlaneClient({ region: "ca-central-1" })

const publishMqtt = async (params: {topic: string, payload: object}) => {
  try {
    
    let topic = params.topic
    let payload = params.payload

    let sendParams: object
    sendParams = {
      topic: topic,
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
      qos: '0'
    }
    
    const command = new PublishCommand(sendParams)

    const response = await clientIoT.send(command)

    return response
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw error.stack
  }
}
```

After run `pnpm run build` I am getting. the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PublishCommandInput'.
  Property 'topic' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Omit<PublishRequest, "payload">'.

40     const command = new PublishCommand(sendParams)

...

333     topic: string | undefined;
            ~~~~~
    'topic' is declared here.


Found 1 error in .../.../.../index.ts:40

 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Any idea in what that could be?

No errors upon `pnpm run build`.

Comment: Why `let sendParams: object;` and then give it a value on the next line? You can just `let sendParams = { ... }`.